# Oracle date comparison as string and as date

Tags: oracle

1) Why is that this doesn't works

```
select * from table where trunc(field1)=to_date('25-AUG-15','DD-MON-YY');

select * from table where trunc(field1)=to_date('25/Aug/15','DD/MON/YY');
```

row is returned in above cases.

So, does this mean that no matter what format the date is there in field1, if it is the valid date and matches with 25th August, it will be returned ( it won't care what format specifier we specify at the right side of the query i.e. DD-MON-YY or DD/MON/YY or anything else) ?

2) but comparsion as string exactly works:

```
select * from table where to_char(field1)=to_char(to_date     

('25/AUG/15','DD/MON/YY'), 'DD/MON/YY');
```

no row is returned as the comparison is performed exactly.

I have field1 as '25-AUG-15' ( although it can be viewed differently doing alter session NLS_DATE_FORMAT...)

field1 is of DATE type

Any help in understanding this is appreciated specifically with respect to point 1

Comment: so print out the values of the to_char functions and see what they are.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does the second query behave the same if you specify the same format in the first cast? `to_char(field1, 'DD/MON/YY')`

Comment: My point is that why for the first case the result is returned without considering the format specifier i.e. it returns the results for 25th August only but it doesn't care about the date format

Comment: Possibly `field1` contains time component that is not 0 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DATE` data type does not have *format* -- it's simply a number. So, a `DATE` 25-Aug-2015 is the same as `DATE` 25/AUG/15, as well as `DATE` 2015-08-15, because it's the same `DATE`.

Strings, on the other hand, are collections of characters, so `'25-Aug-2015'` is obviously different from `'25/AUG/15'`.

In the first example you are comparing `DATE` values. In the second example you are comparing strings.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a field of type **DATE** with value of **The 25th of August 2015**,
but it could be visualized in different ways, what in fact is named **format.**

The **DATE** has format! 
The **DATE** has implicit format defined by Oracle, in your case it is DD-MON-YY, because you see your field as 25-AUG-15.

You can select your data without **TO_DATE** conversion, just matching this **default format** like this:

```
select * from table where trunc(field1)='25-AUG-15';
```

In fact, it's not recommended, because if someone will change the default format, Oracle will not be able to understand that you are going to tell him a **DATE**.

So the **to_date** conversion in this case:

> select * from table where
>   trunc(field1)=to_date('25/AUG/15','DD/MON/YY');

is used to specify that you wanna tell to Oracle a **DATE** type with value of **25th of August 2015**, using a diffrent format, specified as second parameter. (DD/MM/YY in this case).

Comment: Thanks, Just to add to this, can you help that why this both works select * from table where trunc(field1)=to_date('25-AUG-15','DD-MON-YY') and select * from table where trunc(field1)=to_date('25-AUG-15','DD-Mon-YY'); as I believe for 2nd query the input 25-Aug-15 should have worked only

Comment: Because you specify **the same** value, just using different formats, it doesn't matter which is the internal format of oracle, in both case you specify the **DATE** of 25th of August 2015.

Comment: yeah that's correct , but the format valid for 25-AUG-15 is 'DD-MON-YY' and not 'DD-Mon-YY'(this is for 25-Aug-15), isn't that the format version matters here ? eg: I cannot use to_date('25-AUG-15', 'MMDDYY') as this  will throw error

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was my error.(corrected). Happy that you understood.